# Extract columns from df by subset of column id characters

Tags: r

I am working on a gene expression dataset with hundreds of samples.  Each sample in the data frame has a unique column ID (example: OHC_112 of IHC_123).  I want to make a new dataframe containing only the columns containing the "OHC".  How can i do this?

I am struggling to make workable example dataframe... but this is the best i was able to do.

Data frame "DF"

```
        OHC_1   OHC_2   OHC_3   IHC_4   IHC_5   OHC_6
Gene1   1   1   0   1   1   0
Gene2   0   0   0   1   1   0
Gene3   1   1   1   0   0   1
Gene4   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

I got close by using the following subset command

newDF <- subset(DF, ,select = OHC_1:OHC_3)

This allows me to subset the dataframe by a range of the columns but does not allow me to choose all the columns containing "OHC" in the header.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subset the columns with names that match using `grepl`?

```
> DF[, grepl("OHC",names(DF))]
  OHC_1 OHC_2 OHC_3 OHC_6
1     1     1     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     1     1
4     1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shorter call that is also more generalizable with negative-grep:

```
df.2 <- df[, -grep("^OHC_[1:3]$", names(df) )]
```

Since grep returns numerics you can use the negative vector indexing to remove columns. You could add further number or more complex patterns.

Comment: Maybe you mean `"^IHC_[1-3]$"` for your regex?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` with `matches` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>%
   select(matches("^OHC"))
#      OHC_1 OHC_2 OHC_3 OHC_6
#Gene1     1     1     0     0
#Gene2     0     0     0     0
#Gene3     1     1     1     1
#Gene4     1     1     1     0
```